# Why do I get this syntax error by using "min()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry first if this question is too simple. Just start to learn Python.

So here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def minCostClimbingStairs(self, cost: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(cost)
        m = [0] * n

        def dp(self, cost, m, i):
            dp1 = dp(cost, m, i - 1) + cost[i - 1]
            dp2 = dp(cost, m, i - 2) + cost[i - 2]
            return m[i] = min(dp1, dp2)

        return dp(cost, m, n)
```

While I try to run it, it tells me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in line of code `return m[i] = min(dp1, dp2)`

=======> MODIFIED AFTER FEEDBACK

```py
class Solution:
    def minCostClimbingStairs(self, cost: List[int]) -> int:
        m = [0] * (len(cost) + 1)

        def dp(cost, m, i):
            if i <= 1:
                return 0
            if m[i] > 0:
                return m[i]

            dp1 = dp(cost, m, i - 1) + cost[i - 1]
            dp2 = dp(cost, m, i - 2) + cost[i - 2]
            m[i] = min(dp1, dp2)

            return m[i]

        return dp(cost, m, len(cost))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign and return a variable at once in Python, unlike in some other languages. Split that line into two.

```
m[i] = min(dp1, dp2)
return m[i]
```

You do not need `self` in `dp` function since it is a local function and not a class method.

Comment: thank you very much! that works. Also `self` is redundant here.